# Weird interaction between gp.nvim and syntastic

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, plugin-syntastic

I'm using this minimal setup (**note that I'm on Windows and that I couldn't recreate this problem on Linux**):

```
filetype plugin indent on
filetype plugin on

call plug#begin()
Plug 'Robitx/gp.nvim'
Plug 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
call plug#end()

lua require('gp').setup()
```

For some reason after using `:GpChatNew`, writing something in the buffer and then `:GpChatRespond`, I get following error:

`Gp: File "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\nvim-data\\gp\\chats\\timestamp.md" does not look like a chat file`.

In addition to that, `gp.nvim` hotkeys (such as `<C-g><C-g>`) do not work at all in `gp` buffer when `syntastic` is enabled. Removing `syntastic` makes `gp.nvim` work completely as intended.

I tried disabling `syntastic` in gp buffers like following:

```
let g:syntastic_disabled_filetypes = ['markdown']
let g:syntastic_ignore_files = ['\Vgp\\\\chats\\\\', '\Vgp\/chats\/']
```

But neither of these change anything (I've also tried multiple different regex-es such as trivial "chats" etc.).

I have no idea how I can debug this, thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: Syntastic was [deprecated](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#deprecation) two years ago. Consider switching to a maintained plugin.